# Will an intel server motherboard like the W2600CR2 fit into a normal ATX tower?

Tags: motherboard, case

I'm trying to put this motherboard into a "normal" case. But it says the form factor on the motherboard is "custom" Does this mean I have to get an intel server chassis in order to use it?

Comment: http://www.serversupply.com/MOTHERBOARD/DESKTOP%20BOARD/LGA%202011/INTEL/W2600CR2.htm

Answer (score 1):

This is a 4U type board and will fit into a 4U rack or pedestal case / enclosure.

> Board Form Factor  Custom 14.2" x 15"  Chassis Form Factor  4U Rack or
>   Pedestal:

[image: Rack]

[image: Ped]

Reference:
[ARK](http://ark.intel.com/products/56338/Intel-...-Board-W2600CR2)

Comment: Thank you both so much for the fast replies! I'm also referring to the mounting screws though not juts the overall size. I'm concerned unless it's an intel case the holes won't line up.

Comment: Saying "or pedestal case" isn't very helpful.  _Every_ tower-type case is a pedestal case.

Comment: Interesting motherboard size.    Its pretty common for rack mount boards to be strange sizes, but this is the first I have seen that was a custom size for a pedestal/tower board.

Comment: @Jason - it was the term used in ARKs def. case type. Pedestal - tower...either way it is stand up or rack.

Answer (score 0):

Intel [lists the dimensions](http://ark.intel.com/products/56338/Intel-WorkstW2600CR2tion-Board-W2600CR2) at 14.2" x 15" which is significantly larger than either ATX (12" x 9.6") or Extended ATX (12" x 13").

The only chassis they list as compatible is the P4304CR2LFKN.

Answer (score 0):

I installed the motherboard into Rosewill B2-SPIRIT case. You have to remove the bottom hard drive trays which is 4 screws losing three hard drives expansions out of 13. You have to make 6 new risor holes in the case and use two existing holes and use one plastic risor because one hole is too close to end of the metal. After which the board fits perfectly